# How to get name of current rake task in my Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, activemodel

I have some problems with one of gem supporting ActiveModel caching. When I'm using observer for cached model, during application initialization it tries to describe table to get all fields names.

The same thing is done when rake task is running, including db:migration. In that case there is some circular reference error. I'd like to detect current rake task, to skip gem initialization, but I don't know how to find out was code invoked through rake task. How to check it?

Comment: "one of gem supporting ActiveModel caching" - which one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your task via `rake task` or `bundle exec rake task` you can check it in your initializer simply by:

```
if $0.end_with?('rake')
  # rake stuff
else
  # non-rake stuff
end
```

You can use `$PROGRAM_NAME` instead of `$0` if you like.

Answer (score 18):

I dont get exactly what you are trying to do, but here is an example of getting the task name.

```
  task :testing do |task_name|
    puts task_name
  end
```

Comment: If you have namespaced tasks, this should work `puts task_name.name.split(':').last` (in rake v10.4.2).

Comment: Doesn't show how to get the task name in a "Rails model" as the question asks.

Answer (score 12):

This question has been asked a few places, and I didn't think any of the answers were very good... **I** think the answer is to check `Rake.application.top_level_tasks`, which is a list of tasks that will be run.  Rake doesn't necessarily run just *one* task.

Comment: Yup, the question asked about getting the name and the selected answer shows how to detect if you're in a rake task. This is the right answer.

Comment: I think this is more elegant than adding `do |task name|`.